# batch processing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering how do you access Input elements that have an id or name code for e.g. row_1_firstname and row_2_firstname - when you don't know exactly how may rows you have, how do you do batch inserts and how do you query the Input::get or Input::all() with undetermined number of rows for an insert and update procedure

```
public function store()
{
     $array = Input::all();
     foreach($array as $element) {
          // do stuff in here
          // store data in a array for batch insert and update processing 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for naming input as arrays `firstname[]` and hidden inputs `ids[]` with id to edit

```
public function store()
{       
     $names = Input::get('firstname');
     $ids = Input::get('ids');

     for ($i=0, $c = count($ids); $i<$c; ++$i) {
         echo $names[$i].' was set for id '.$ids[$i];
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to insert multiple records into array you can do it this way:

```
public function store()
{       
     $names = Input::get('firstname');
     $surnames = Input::get('surname');

     $data_array = [];    
     for ($i=0, $c = count($names); $i<$c; ++$i) {
          $record = [];
          $record['name'] = $names[$i];
          $record['surname'] = $surnames[$i];
          $data_array[] = $record;  
     }
     DB::table('users')->insert($data_array);
}
```

Comment: so then how would you go about create the $data_array that contains all the array that contains the information  for insertion - like building the array up so I can use my model to something like ProductVariations::insert($data_array);

Comment: it's building that array is a problem since I've never done this type of code before

Comment: @KDM I've added example with inserting into database

Comment: Thanks heaps for you're answer

Answer (score 0):

Separating `firstnames[]` and `ids[]` and any other field you need is one way, but definitely not the most straightforward.

I suggest instead adding your inputs like:

```
// assuming you add users
users[1][firstname]
users[1][lastname]
users[2][firstname]
users[2][lastname]
...
```

of course `users[1]` is controlled via js and it's dynamic `users[i]`.

Then in your PHP code you can do simply this:

```
$users = Input::get('users');

// validate input according to your needs, then:

DB::table('users')->insert($users);
```